# Relation Between Compressed Sensing and Incoherence

Tags: discrete-signals, compressive-sensing

I am working on CS. I know that as coherence decreases (or incoherence increases) compressed sensing results improve. I know how to calculate the coherence, but I can't find an exact equation between incoherence and compressed sensing. I would like to know the equation relating coherence and CS with lower and higher limits.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no general equation - you'll have to investigate the performance (in the mean squared error sense) empirically.

Answer (score 3):

The coherence can be used to bound the number of measurements $m$ required for successful reconstruction as seen for example in equation (6) in [Candès & Wakin 2008](http://dsp.rice.edu/files/cs/CSintro.pdf):
$$m ≥ C \cdot \mu^2(\Phi, \Psi)\cdot S  \cdot \log n$$
where $C$ is some positive constant, $S$ is the sparsity, and $n$ is the size of the sparse signal.

One problem, however, is that this is not a very sharp bound. [Donoho & Tanner 2010](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/tanner/papers/DoTa_PUT.pdf#page=8), for example, describe some brief history of this in Section X of the linked paper. I have not followed the development on this aspect of compressed sensing for a long time, so I do not know if there are newer or better explanations. So, in my opinion, the best you can use the coherence for in practice is as a rule of thumb: the less coherence, the better.

Comment: Thansk,..Is there is any equation connecting Compressed sensing and mutual incoherence

Comment: I added an equation to the answer that uses the mutual coherence to bound the required number of measurements.

Comment: Thanks,Can you tell me the limits/bounds.How far we can go or what is the minmum value of m that can be choosed

Comment: In my experience, the phase transition bounds from Donoho & Tanner are the most realistic and reflect practical performance well for l1 reconstruction. I would look at that instead of coherence if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

Coherence and incoherence with respect to compressive sensing is a feature that has to be implemented when designing your sensing matrix. See if my write up below could be of any help.

**Incoherence:** This is the property of the sensing matrix $A$ that aids to determine the recovery ability of $A$ [(Joel, 2003)](http://web.math.princeton.edu/tfbb/spring03/greed-ticam0304.pdf) [(David & Michael, 2002)](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~donoho/Reports/2002/OptSparse.pdf).

It is specifically used to determine the sufficient condition for $L_0$ and $L_1$ unique solutions (Heung-No, 2011 - *Introduction to compressive sensing: With coding theory perspective*). The coherence of the sensing matrix $A$ ($\mu(A)$)   is the largest absolute, relative inner product between two columns $A_i$ and $A_j$ of the sensing matrix $A$ as given in (1) below [(Emmanuel et al., 2010)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2613).
$$
\mu(A) = \max_{j<k} \frac{|\langle A_j,A_k \rangle|}{\|A_j\|_2 \|A_k\|_2} \tag{1}
$$
This property of $A$ is easier to evaluate than RIP of $A$, reason being that the computational complexity of evaluating $\mu(A)$ scales exponentially with the number of columns in $A$ (Dennis, S. 2012).  The relationship between coherence and spark of $A$ is given in (2) - see reference in [(Marco, 2009)](https://cnx.org/contents/9wtroLnw@5.12:YcCc-ZVZ@5/Coherence). If (2) holds, then for each measured vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^M$  there exist at most one signal $x$ such that  $Ax=b  + \epsilon$ holds. 
$$
k < \frac{1}{2} \left(1 + \frac{1}{\mu(A)} \right) \tag{2}
$$

Comment: I've tried to use mathjax to enter the equations, but (1) is beyond my divining powers!  If you can point me to the "Richard" reference, I'll try to fix it.